# Why does my web API post method get null parameter?

Tags: asp.net

I have a web API project with a controller like this:

```
namespace Api.Controllers
{

public class StudyController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/PostReviewedStudyData")]
    [HttpPost]
    public bool PostReviewedStudyData([FromBody]string jsonStudy)
    {
       ApiStudy study = JsonHelper.JsonDeserialize<ApiStudy>(jsonStudy);
       BusinessLogics.BL.SaveReviewedStudyDataToDb(study); 
       return true;
    }

    [Route("api/GetStudyData/{studyUid}")]
    [HttpGet, HttpPost]
    public string GetStudyData(string studyUid)
    {
        ApiStudy study = BusinessLogics.BL.GetStudyObject(studyUid);
        return JsonHelper.JsonSerializer<ApiStudy>(study);
    }
}
}
```

I call it like this, from another application:

```
HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http://localhost:60604/api/PostReviewedStudyData");
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
string postData = Api.JsonHelper.JsonSerializer<ApiStudy>(s);
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

httpWReq.Method = "POST";
httpWReq.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
httpWReq.ContentLength = data.Length;
httpWReq.Accept = "application/json";

using (Stream stream = httpWReq.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();

string responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

My breakpoint at the post method is hit, but the jsonStudy object is null. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First of all what i notice is this:

```
HttpWebRequest httpWReq =    (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http://localhost:60604/api/PostReviewedStudy Data");
```

you have a space in the PostReviewedStudy Data also if that does not work try removing  the content type line and see if it works

Comment: Thank you Chino, If I remove the content type, I get Unsupported data type exception. The space was just when copying.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
[Route("api/PostReviewedStudyData")]
[HttpPost]
public bool PostReviewedStudyData([FromBody]ApiStudy study)
{
   BusinessLogics.BL.SaveReviewedStudyDataToDb(study); 
   return true;
}
```

WebApi supports fully typed parameters, there's no need to convert from a JSON string.